# check for null response using getJson method

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Just finishing up an app and I need to implement one more thing on the json side of things.

I have a jquery auto complete which uses a web service I wrote which returns json.

I need to alter this a slight bit so that if the first request with paramaters returns null then it will try again with a default url without paramters which does a master search.

Just to be sure I'm not missing any tricks I said I'd ask and see if any jquery gurus have an elegant way of  achieving this.

```
var cache = {},lastXhr;
var web_service_url_default = "http://json_sample.php";
var web_service_url_specific = "http://json_sample.php/?param1=hello&param2=world";

var autocomp_opt = {
        minLength: 1,
        source: function( request, response ) {
            var term = request.term;
            if ( term in cache ) {
                response( cache[ term ] );
                return;
            }

            lastXhr = $.getJSON( web_service_url_specific, request, function( data, status, xhr ) {
                cache[ term ] = data;
                if ( xhr === lastXhr ) {
                    response( data );
                }
            });
        }
};
```

That is my options variable for the auto complete which is input to the auto-complete call as follows and which works fine.

```
$('.some_class').autocomplete(autocomp_opt);
```

I need to alter it so that if the first request returns empty then it fires the default request with no params.

Cheers for the help as always.

---

**Updated with working example**

Got this done, see the following code in case it helps anyone. It may not be the most elegant but it works anyway.

Note that in this example and in testing the caching did not seem to play nice and caused the request not to be fired now and again so I removed it. Now it works 100%.

```
var autocomp_opt = {
            minLength: 1,
            source: function( request, response ) {
                var term = request.term;

                lastXhr = $.getJSON( web_service_url_specific, request, function( data, status, xhr ) {
// check if there is only one entry in the json response and if the value is null, my json script returns empty like this
                        if(data.length == 1 && data[0].value == null){
                            $.getJSON( $web_service_url_default, request, function( data, status, xhr ) {
                                response( data );
                            });
                        }else{
                            response( data );
                        }
                });
            }
        };

$('.some_class').autocomplete(autocomp_opt);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `if ( xhr === lastXhr )` will never be true.

Comment: indeed, that was directly from the jquery-ui site example so was in there under their caching example. I had pondered it myself. I actually got this working myself and took your suggestion about xhr into account too. thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(data.length == 1 && data[0].value == null) 
{
    ...
}
```

I managed to get this one working myself. See the example above if it helps anyone. It might not be the most elegant way to do this but it works nonetheless.
Cheers.

Comment: You should post your complete solution in your answer, not your question.

Answer (score 0):

I assume an "empty request return" means a request failure (e.g. error, not empty string or so). You could build your ajax call with $.ajax and hook into the error function:

```
$.ajax({
  url: web_service_url_specific,
  data: request,
  dataType, 'json',
  success: function( data, status, xhr ) {
    // not going to question this part
    cache[ term ] = data;
    if ( xhr === lastXhr ) { response( data ); }
  },
  error: function() {
    // fallback ajax call
    $.ajax({});
  }
});
```